# Bagging classifier vs RandomForestClassifier

Tags: machine-learning, classification, scikit-learn, ensemble-learning

Is there a difference between using a bagging classifier with base_estimaton=DecisionTreeClassifier and using just the RandomForestClassifier? This question refers to models from python library called sklearn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference. In sklearn if you bag decision trees, you still end up using all features with each decision tree. In random forests however, you use a subset of features.

The official [sklearn documentation on ensembling methods](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html) could have been a bit more clear about the difference, here is what it says:

1. "*When samples are drawn with replacement, then the method is known as Bagging*"
2. "*In random forests (see RandomForestClassifier and RandomForestRegressor classes), each tree in the ensemble is built from a sample drawn with replacement (i.e., a bootstrap sample) from the training set*."

So it would appear there is no difference if you bag decision trees, right? It turns out, the documentation also states:

"*Furthermore, when splitting each node during the construction of a tree, the best split is found either from all input features or a random subset of size* `max_features`."

So this is one more way of introducing randomness, by limiting the number of features at the splits. In practice, it is useful to indeed tune `max_features` to get a good fit.

Comment: It's not each *tree* that receives a subset of candidate features, it's each *split*.

Comment: @Matthew Drury Thank you for point out, corrected.